# Why is java.util.logging unpopular?

Tags: java, logging

Can someone explain what is wrong with java.util.logging framework and why should other logging framework like log4j/logback or slf4j should be prefered?

Comment: Reading: http://glauche.de/2009/09/09/java-util-logging-vs-slf4j/